# How to get all the solution points over a finite field of an elliptical curve?

Tags: sage

I'm trying to follow a youtube explanation of elliptic curves, and at [this point](https://youtu.be/grzFM5XciAY?t=110) the presenter defines the following elliptic curve:

```
E = EllipticCurve([2,5])
```

and proceeds to find the number of solutions over Fp with p = 5, which I supposed it means Z/5Z (i.e. modulo 5) as

```
E.Np(5)
```

Since there are two solutions, I don't think I understand what is going on. I only see (0,0) as a possible integer over the field Z/5Z.

Naturally, I want to see the solutions, but the closer I get is to print out the points after redefining the function as follows:

```
print(EllipticCurve(Zmod(5),(2,5)).points())
```

The output is:

```
[(0 : 0 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0)]
```

Now this I think, means the point `(0,0)`. I found online that the second point is the point at infinity. In this case the number of solution is really 1, not 2, and the function E.Np(5) would be overcounting (most likely not).

How can I extract all the points in a simpler way, and make sure that `E.Np(5)` makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When discussing points on elliptic curves, we really mean *projective points on elliptic curves*. That is, instead of considering the curve `E: Y^2 = X^3 + 2X + 5`, we really consider the curve `E: Y^2 Z = X^3 + 2 X Z^2 + 5 Z^3`, a homogenous expression where every term has degree 3. And in this form, we consider two points `(a : b : c)` and `(A : B : C)` to be the same if one tuple is a multiple of the other (where these mean the x, y, z coordinates of a point).

This is a "smooth projective elliptic curve", where I emphasize that the word *projective* is what means that we homogenize and consider three-variable points. The alternative, without homogenizing, is called an *affine* curve.

It turns out that the properties of elliptic curves are much nicer and more uniform when considered as projective curves. When a mathematician talks about an elliptic curve, it is common to flip between projective and affine coordinates. Unfortunately, it is also common to abuse notation and refer to the *projective* curve by its *affine* model. But the "true" object is typically the projective object. This is happening implicitly in your video.

Every elliptic curve will have a point at infinity, given by the coordinate `(0 : 1 : 0)`. We can check that this is a point on the curve by checking that setting `X = 0, Y = 1, Z = 0` in projective coordinates. The other coordinate is indeed `(0 : 0 : 1)`, which corresponds to the affine coordinate `(0, 0)`.

In sage, you have identified the right way to count solutions over a finite field:

```py
E5 = EllipticCurve(GF(5), [2, 5])
E5.points()
# [(0 : 0 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0)]
```

One can check that the underlying data is stored projectively too. We take the affine point `(0, 0)` and compute its point. Then we have sage print it back to us (it gives it to us in projective coordinates). One reason is that the rational points form a group and can be added together: and adding this point to itself gives the point at infinity!

```py
P = E5([0, 0])  # the point (0, 0)
print(P)
# (0 : 0 : 1)
print(P + P)
# (0 : 1 : 0)
```

To restrict only to affine points, you need to ignore the point `(0 : 1 : 0)`. If you compare affine point counts to the others in the video, you'll find that you're always off by one, due to the projective point `(0 : 1 : 0)`.

For example, we can directly compare.

```py
def naive_find_points_mod(modulus):
    i = 1
    for x in range(modulus):
        for y in range(modulus):
            if (y^2 - (x^3 + 2*x + 5)) % modulus == 0:
                print(f"{i}: (x, y) = ({x}, {y})")
                i += 1
print(E.Np(7)) # 7 points
naive_find_points_mod(7)
# prints out
# 1 (x, y) = (1, 1)
# 2 (x, y) = (1, 6)
# 3 (x, y) = (4, 0)
# 4 (x, y) = (5, 0)
# 5 (x, y) = (6, 3)
# 6 (x, y) = (6, 4)
# Only 6 points! The missing point is the point at infinity
```

Finally, the simple algorithm in `naive_find_points_mod` is one possible answer to your last question, looking for a direct algorithm. The point here is that there are only p^2 affine points mod p, and one could check them all if p isn't too large. As p gets larger, there are some very nontrivial algorithms that one can use, but that's a different subject.

Comment: Thank you very much. I started reading your answer, and was absolutely delighted. But while I have you attention, for modulo 7, I get an error if I try your initial approach (for modulo 5): `E5 = EllipticCurve(GF(7), [2, 5]); E5.points()` It reads: 'ArithmeticError: y^2 = x^3 + 2*x + 5 defines a singular curve'. Can you please shed some light on what's going on there? Thank you!

Comment: Elliptic curves are supposed to be *smooth* projective curves. In my answer, I emphasized *projective*, but the error you see is about *smooth*. To be singular means that the curve has either cusps or self-intersections (or more formally, points where the tangents are undefined). To be singular when considered mod p is called "having bad reduction mod p". You can see this in sage via `E.has_bad_reduction(7)`. (E will have bad reduction at 2, 7, and 101, which are the prime factors of `E.discriminant()`).

Comment: Also, it is possible (though not necessarily helpful) to make a singular (and thus non-elliptic) curve coming from a singular reduction of an elliptic curve. For example: `F = GF(7)` to name the ground field, `A.<x, y> = F[]` to make a polynomial ring over Z/7Z in two variables, and then `C = Curve(y^2 - (x^3 + 2*x + 5))` makes the curve. You can see that it's singular with `C.is_singular()`. Further, `C.singular_points()` shows that the problem point is `(5, 0)`.

Comment: Great! This makes sense. So when there is a wrinkle in the curve, if you want the actual points, you have to get them ad hoc with something along the naive method in your last function?

Comment: In this case, you can proceed with `C.rational_points()` (as a rational point over Z/7Z is just a typical integer point) for singular curves. But in fact what sage does by default is **exactly** the naive enumeration as I wrote above. Good luck!